# Ionic2 - Ion-select broken in specific page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm doing an Ionic 2 app, the problem is when going to a specific page the ion-select component does not work and show properly, but on other pages this component works.

Here is the TypeScript file:

```
// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-filter',
  templateUrl: 'new-filter.html'
})

export class NewFilterPage {
  form: FormGroup;
  accountId: number;
  localFolders: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams, private platform: Platform, private folders: 
FoldersProvider, private auth: AuthProvider, private formBuilder: 
FormBuilder) {
    this.accountId = navParams.get('id');

    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      type: ["", Validators.required],
      filterText: ["", Validators.required],
      folder: ["", Validators.required]
    });

    this.localFolders = [];

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.folders.getLocalFolders(this.accountId).then((data: any) => {

        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.item(i)));
          this.localFolders.push(data.item(i));
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.localFolders));
        console.log(this.accountId);
    });
  });
 }

 // ...

 // ...
}
```

My HTML file:

```
...

<ion-list>
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Filtrar por...</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="type" name="type">
      <ion-option value="ssw" selected="true">Asunto comienza por</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="sc">El asunto contiene</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="si">El asunto es</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="fc">El remitente contiene</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  ...

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Enviar los mensajes a...</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="folder">
      <ion-option value="1" selected="true">Prueba</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="2">Prueba1</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="3">Prueba2</ion-option>

    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  ...

</form>
```

package.json:

```
/*...*/

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": "^2.6.5",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.1.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
/* ... */
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
}
```

Output of `ionic info` command:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
Cordova CLI      :  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on. 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0

System:

Node       : v7.10.0
OS         : Linux 4.4
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Screenshots of the app running, these ion-select does not work:

[image: Broken ion-select]
[image: Broken ion-select 2]

Also selected multiple radio buttons are allowed:

[image: Broken radio buttons]

However, this ion-select of a different page works:

[image: Working1]
[image: Working2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have used the **ngModel** directive in the page for which the ion-select function works?
From the ionic -documentation [Ionic Select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) , the proper way of using `<ion-select>`is

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
<ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
<ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Yes, there are no [(ngModel)] in the working ion-selects [http://i.imgur.com/hyN5EOm.png](http://i.imgur.com/hyN5EOm.png) [http://i.imgur.com/y4K3T7g.png](http://i.imgur.com/y4K3T7g.png)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, all I had to do was updating dependencies to solve this problem.